# Strange attempted emails from Cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, email

I use Zoho for my email client and last night I got a couple of notifications saying:

> Warning! Unverified sender. The system could not verify if this email
> was sent by root@servername.com. Do not click any links or open any
> attachments, if any, in this email.

The first one was the following:

```
subject: Cron <root@servername> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
message: run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/do-agent exited with return code 100
```

and then about an hour later:

```
subject: Cron <root@servername>    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
message: run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/droplet-agent exited with return code 4
```

Not sure what to make of this. At first I thought someone gained access to my server. But I am not really sure. I am by no means an expert on the server side. This is just my DigitalOcean droplet that I do mostly development on and host a couple personal sites.

So since the message had `run-parts:` in it if figured I would check out the cron jobs. Here is the contents the `cron.daily` directory `.placeholder  apport  apt-compat  do-agent  dpkg  logrotate  man-db` and the `cron.hourly` folder has the following in it  `.placeholder  droplet-agent`. I don't see anything crazy here.

So then looking at the first email I see `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )`. But I don't have `anacron` in my `/usr/sbin/` directory.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Is this something I should be worried about? Why am I receiving these emails? I haven't done anything new on here in a quite a while so it's not like I added something new or anything like that.

Update:

Contents of `/etc/cron.daily/do-agent`

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/bash /opt/digitalocean/do-agent/scripts/update.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Contents of `/opt/digitalocean/do-agent/scripts/update.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# vim: noexpandtab

REPO_HOST=https://repos.insights.digitalocean.com
REPO_GPG_KEY_CURRENT=${REPO_HOST}/sonar-agent-current.asc

main() {
        # add some jitter to prevent overloading the packaging machines
        sleep $(( RANDOM % 900 ))

        export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
        if command -v apt-get 2&>/dev/null; then
                curl -sL "${REPO_GPG_KEY_CURRENT}" | apt-key add -
                apt-get -qq update -o Dir::Etc::SourceParts=/dev/null -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup=no -o Dir::Etc::SourceL>
                apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -qq install -y --only>
        elif command -v yum 2&>/dev/null; then
                rpm --import "${REPO_GPG_KEY_CURRENT}"
                yum -q -y --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="digitalocean-agent" makecache
                yum -q -y update do-agent
        fi
}

main
```

Comment: Check what is inside `/etc/cron.daily/do-agent`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I only have one thing in there `/bin/bash /opt/digitalocean/do-agent/scripts/update.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Check what this script do: `/opt/digitalocean/do-agent/scripts/update.sh`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have updated the question with the contents of these files

Comment: When a server is doing something and I don't understand why, the first thing I assume is I have misconfigured something.

Comment: @Paul do you have any insight into what that misconfiguration would be. I would have thought that if I had seen these emails right after I configured the server. But it has had the same configuration for months and this is the first and only time this happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing strange. The command check if you have `/usr/sbin/anacron` and if file do not exist or not executable run `run-parts` for daily `cron`. And usually `cron` send mail to `root` with the job results. If tou want to stop add as first line in `cron.daily` line like:

```
MAILTO=
```

Same about `cron.hourly`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I just kind of find it weird that its in the cron.daily and this is the first and only time I've seen these emails in my Zoho inbox. You would have thought it would be a frequent occurance but it was just once.

Comment: @SteveK, maybe other mails was filtered by mail system. And for me this mail looks perfectly legitime (from cron)